# Can I change name of tankauth admin controller to be harder to find for baddies?

Tags: codeigniter, security, tankauth

I think I should change the name of my TankAuth admin controller.  The login page for my admin area is www.mysite.com/admin which is the first thing any mal-intented person or bot crawling the web for loop holes would guess. Before I make a mess of the code I'd like to know if there is a routine practice perform this change?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are no admin url configs for Tank Auth - you'll have to simply change it all manually